# MQTT for large architectures

Tags: architecture, arduino, mqtt, iot, esp8266

I am looking to implement MQTT architecture for a building. Around 1000+ nodes are communicating and interchanging data with broker. This communication is two way i mean data is subscribed & published too. I want to know, can MQTT handle two way communication for 1000+ nodes? Is't it get any conflict?
BTW, we are using ESP8266 chip at node side.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of question is impossible to answer without knowing way more about the situation you intend to deploy.

MQTT is a protocol not a solution, the size of the deployment entirely depends on the following:

- number of clients
- size of the messages being sent
- rate of message being sent
- type of broker (single instance/distributed cluster)
- type of network infrastructure involved

1000's of clients is nothing compared to some of the deployments from IBM/Amazon/Microsoft.

Your best bet is to build a test rig and test it to see how much resources your specific scenario uses.

Comment: Clients : 1000 (approx)
Size of message: few bits (1 byte hardly) 
No brand-width issue